# Could track mdm ios/android device/user profiles restrictions?

Tags: android, ios, mdm, payload, airwatch

I have a mobile app in ios and android platforms. Our some customers are distributing it in mdm(many even use airwatch). Airwatch has some restriction payloads like: "Allow use of camera", "Allow screen capture", "Allow Biometric ID modification" etc.(these are ios/android device/user profiles restrictions) I want to take action in my mobile apps according to these payloads. For example there is an upload option with camera. I want to that if "Allow use of camera" is set as false, I want to not showing camera option.

Could track these payloads form ios and android apps? If yes, how to make it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at android.content.RestrictionsManager.
getApplicationRestrictions() will return a Bundle of restrictions.

[RestrictionsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/RestrictionsManager)

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is for app restriction, isn't it? I want to get device restriction (device profile restriction). Could I take device restriction from app?